# Custom function gets called once more at every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I've set up a basic HTML page with a table of items.
I want to be able to delete each item separately, so I added a column containing a delete button for each row of my HTML table.
This is what this column looks like.

```
<td headers="deleteRoleHeader" class="cell-texte">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="deleteRole();"></span>
</td>
```

And my Angular JS function:

```
$scope.deleteRole = function(){
    var data = {
                codeRole: $scope.code_role,
                descRole : $scope.desc_role
               };
    console.log(data);
};
```

My problem is each time I click on my delete button, my function gets called once more than the previous time.
To clarify: first time I click, function is called once, second time I click, function is called twice, etc.

I would like my function to be called only once when I click on my delete button.

Has anyone faced a similar issue ?
I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions about functions being called multiple times but I haven't been able to fix my issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: here's my console output after two clicks
[image: Example]

EDIT 2: **I figured out what what causing the problem: I had a modal set up, acting as a confirmation and if I remove it my code behaves as it should (only one call is made to the function)**
Here is a fiddle that reproduces the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/w6edum0f/12/.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.roles = [
{
    "codeRole": "test",
    "descRole": "test desc"
  },
  {"codeRole": "test2",
    "descRole": "test desc1"
  }
];
  $scope.selectRole = function(role) {
    $scope.code_role = role.codeRole;
    $scope.desc_role = role.descRole;
  };

    $scope.deleteRole = function(){
        $('#deleteModal').show();
        $('#deleteBtn').click(function(){
            $('#deleteModal').hide();
            var data = {
                codeRole: $scope.code_role,
                descRole : $scope.desc_role
            };
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: what data do you get printed to your log? Is it the same for all function calls?

Comment: I get the data from the line I clicked. Here's an example of one of my HTM table lines: Role 1  | User | Delete button. In my function I would get the data regarding this line but displayed several times.

Comment: Nothing stands out in your code as being the cause of this. As it's a small example, can you put your code in a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem in action? This will help us narrow down the cause.

Comment: So after clicking the `span` twice you see `data` logged three times?

Comment: I see my data being printed out once more at every click.

Comment: That's a little ambiguous Yaoming. That could mean that after 4 clicks it's in your console 4 times, or it's in your console 10 times. Can you confirm which?

Comment: You said that. It's not clear that it means the same thing to you that it does me. After clicking the `span` twice, how many times has `data` been printed?

Comment: After clicking the span twice, data is printed twice so if I click the span X times, data will be displayed X times (plus all the previous iterations still in my console output of course). So if I click twice, I actually have 3 entries in my console.

Comment: Could you check you're not calling data anywhere else in your project? And just in case, can you try to use let instead of var just to make the data block scoped?

Comment: add debugger in function, and try to debug the code, and see the call stack, it might help you, at least you will be sure, from where the code is being called

Comment: I have added a fiddle that shows the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first time I click, function is called once, second time I click, function is called twice, etc.

That happens because the code is adding another click handler on each call:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.deleteRole = function(){
>     $('#deleteModal').show();
>     $('#deleteBtn').click(function(){
>         $('#deleteModal').hide();
>         var data = {
>             codeRole: $scope.code_role,
>             descRole : $scope.desc_role
>         };
>         console.log(data);
>     });
> };
> ```

One solution is to remove the click handler once called:

```
$scope.deleteRole = function(){
    $('#deleteModal').show();
    $('#deleteBtn').on("click", hideModal);
};
function hideModal(){
    $('#deleteModal').hide();
    $('#deleteBtn').off("click", hideModal); 
    var data = {
        codeRole: $scope.code_role,
        descRole : $scope.desc_role
    };
    console.log(data);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, guys, I try to make a small angular app and try to run this same code, so that we will be in same context:

link to jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/nd8wm5pg/1/

***REASON:*** Reason is the bubbling, when we click on `okay` button from the dialog, which opens after clicking `delete`, then bubbling starts, so to handle bubling, i try following trick, you can try another if you want :P

```
  $scope.deleteRole = function(){
         $('#deleteModal').show();
         var isDeleteBtnClicked = false;
            $('#deleteBtn').click(function($event){
                if(!isDeleteBtnClicked)
                {
                    $('#deleteModal').hide();
                    var data = {
                        codeRole: $scope.code_role,
                               descRole : $scope.desc_role
                           };
                    console.log(data);
                    isDeleteBtnClicked = true;
                }

        });
    };
```

And following is the running code snippet:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>deleteRole
        <th><span>Code</span>
        </th>
        <th><span>Description</span>
        </th>
        <th>
          Suppression
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <div>
        <div>
          <tr ng-repeat="role in roles" 
          ng-click="selectRole(role);">
            <td>{{ role.codeRole }}</td>
            <td>{{ role.descRole }}</td>
            <td>
              <span title="Supprimer le rôle" 
              ng-click="deleteRole();">Delete</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<div id="deleteModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h1>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Voulez-vous supprimer l'élément ?</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Supprimer</button>
      <button type="button" id="cancelDeleteBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.roles = [
{
    "codeRole": "test",
    "descRole": "test desc"
  },
  {"codeRole": "test2",
    "descRole": "test desc1"
  }
];
  $scope.selectRole = function(role) {
    $scope.code_role = role.codeRole;
    $scope.desc_role = role.descRole;
  };

    $scope.deleteRole = function(){
      $('#deleteModal').show();
   var isDeleteBtnClicked = false;
      $('#deleteBtn').click(function($event){
    if(!isDeleteBtnClicked)
    {
     $('#deleteModal').hide();
     var data = {
      codeRole: $scope.code_role,
          descRole : $scope.desc_role
         };
     console.log(data);
     isDeleteBtnClicked = true;
    }
        
        });
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if still have doubt, please let me know

Comment: i am working on it, i think will give you solution in 10 mints